Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/bidi/HasBiDi
Can anyone please help me to solve this error? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/bidi/HasBiDi
I tried many times but unable to resolve this. In maven project I added the latest version of selenium
enter image description here
I am unable to find the solution for this so please give me the solution. enter image description here

Please edit your question and share the <dependencies> section of your pom.xml. In case you have a parent pom, then you would need to share its contents as well.
